# Círculo entre elementos inline-block no firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Gostaria de saber o que são esses círculos inseridos entre alguns elementos com display inline-block no mozilla firefox, pois eles ocupam espaço e atrapalham o layout.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Quando se usa `display: inline-block` e os elementos (div, span, etc) tem espaços entre eles, o browser (não só o firefox) acrescente `4px` de espaço entre os elementos, isso é algo que vem sendo discutido a muitos anos e anda não implementaram uma propriedade CSS que remova isso usando inline-block, mas há várias formas de resolver isso.

Algumas delas:

Não deixar espaços entre os elementos:

```
<div>div inline-block 1</div><div>div inline-block 2</div>
```

Comentar os espaços

```
<div>div inline-block 1</div><!--
--><div>div inline-block 2</div>
```

Usar margens negativas, etc...

Para mais informações veja essa postagem:

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

O que eu utilizo atualmente que pra mim é a melhor opção, é uma fonte da Adobe chamada [Adobe Blank](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/adobe-blank), que remove esse "Carectere", então você declara na div pai a fonte Adobe Blank, e nas divs filhas você declara a fonte que desejar.